# nvarchar value in combobox won't filter data if value is Cyrillic, in Latin it does

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, combobox, textbox

I have a method that is filling my combobox

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    // DO REMEMBER TO OPEN THE CONNECTION!!!  
    conn.Open();

    // Connection Established  
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM monitoring", conn);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string item = reader[11].ToString();
            comboBoxPretraga.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Also,I have a DropDownClosed event.It is supposed to get the value from combo,and based on that to fill textbox with the data from the same row.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    conn.Open();

    // Connection Established  
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM monitoring monitoring where konzervator_ime_prezime='" + comboBoxPretraga.Text + "'", conn);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string tlo = reader[2].ToString();
            textBox_TloI.Text = tlo;
        }
    }
}
```

When I start my app, right values are in the combobox.
But when I select a value that is in Cyrillic(example: фдгдфгд), textBox_TloI doesn't get any data.
But when I select a value that is latinic, it works fine. The problem is in combobox value. Because, If I select something latin from combo, it will display Cyrillic in textbox.
It just doesn't seem to get the right Cyrillic value for filtering from the combobox.

Comment: [Parameterized SQL: just say yes](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/)

Comment: try to do where xx = N'some text'

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting the txt of the text box you may need set the culture info

```
string tlo = reader[2].ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: there is a problem with this..it says no overload method ToString takes 1 argument..

Comment: Take a look at this link [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)